# CompileJava Task fails with errors while their are no compilation issues GRADLE 7.5

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, gradle, build.gradle, querydsl

I have a project where I have configured QueryDSL using gradle. Below is my Gradle config.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'com.avios.cp'
version = '1.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    customClassPath.extendsFrom implementation
    querydsl.extendsFrom annotationProcessor
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.avios:component-starter:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.11'
    annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jpa"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

clean {
    delete 'gensrc'
}

task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build', description: 'Generates query types for entities') {

    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += ['gensrc/main/java']
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = configurations.customClassPath
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor",
            "com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor"
    ]
    destinationDir = file('gensrc/main/java')
}

build {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    dependsOn compileJava
    tasks.findByName('compileJava').mustRunAfter 'generateQueryDSL'
}
```

The below statement in build.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.avios:component-starter:1.0.0'
```

It is a custom library made by me and published locally which have all the required dependencies.

The issue is when I am running

```
gradlew clean build
```

The Q Files are being generated at the required source folder. But once generateQueryDSL is completing compileJava starts. But it is failing with below errors

```
gradlew clean build

> Task :compileJava FAILED
warning: unknown enum constant com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL
  reason: class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Include not found
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\ComponentFndApplication.java:3: error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
                               ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\ComponentFndApplication.java:4: error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
                                             ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\ComponentFndApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootApplication
 ^
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:7: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Column;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:8: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Entity;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:9: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:10: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:11: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Id;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:12: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:13: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Table;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:15: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
                                       ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
 ^
  symbol: class Entity
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Dish.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
@Table(name = "dish")
 ^
  symbol: class Table
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:3: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Column;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:4: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:5: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Entity;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:6: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:7: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:8: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:9: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Table;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:11: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
                                       ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
 ^
  symbol: class Entity
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDish.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
@Table(name = "food_in_dish")
 ^
  symbol: class Table
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDishId.java:6: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Column;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDishId.java:7: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\FoodInDishId.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
@Embeddable
 ^
  symbol: class Embeddable
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:7: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:8: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Column;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:9: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Entity;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:10: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:11: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:12: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Id;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:13: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:14: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Table;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:16: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
                                       ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
 ^
  symbol: class Entity
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\Food.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
@Table(name = "food")
 ^
  symbol: class Table
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:5: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:6: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Column;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:7: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Entity;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:8: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:9: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:10: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Id;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:11: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:12: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:13: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:14: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Table;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:16: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
                                       ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
 ^
  symbol: class Entity
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfile.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
@Table(name = "nutrient_profile")
 ^
  symbol: class Table
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:5: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Column;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:6: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Entity;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:7: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:8: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:9: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Id;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:10: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:11: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:12: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Table;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:14: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
                                       ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
 ^
  symbol: class Entity
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientProfileDetail.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
@Table(name = "nutrient_profile_detail")
 ^
  symbol: class Table
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:5: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:6: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Column;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:7: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Entity;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:8: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:9: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:10: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Id;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:11: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:12: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Table;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:14: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
                                       ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
 ^
  symbol: class Entity
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientType.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
@Table(name = "nutrient_type")
 ^
  symbol: class Table
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:5: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:6: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Column;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:7: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Entity;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:8: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:9: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:10: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Id;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:11: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:12: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.Table;
                        ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:14: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
                                       ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
@Entity
 ^
  symbol: class Entity
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\entity\NutrientSubType.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
@Table(name = "nutrient_subtype")
 ^
  symbol: class Table
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\DishController.java:6: error: package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
                                                   ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\DishController.java:7: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\DishController.java:8: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\DishController.java:9: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\DishController.java:10: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\DishController.java:11: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\DishController.java:12: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\DishController.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
@RestController
 ^
  symbol: class RestController
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\DishController.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
@RequestMapping("/fnd/dish")
 ^
  symbol: class RequestMapping
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\FoodController.java:6: error: package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
                                                   ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\FoodController.java:7: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\FoodController.java:8: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\FoodController.java:9: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\FoodController.java:10: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\FoodController.java:11: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\FoodController.java:12: error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
                                              ^
D:\Development\Workspaces\STS_Workspaces\9Oct2021\component-fnd\src\main\java\com\avios\cp\fnd\rest\FoodController.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
@RestController
 ^
  symbol: class RestController
warning: unknown enum constant Include.NON_NULL
  reason: class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Include not found
100 errors
2 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

It seems that compileJava not able to find the dependencies. I don't have any compilation issues in my IDE. Below is the screenshot of project dependencies.

[Project Dependencies Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Fce.jpg)

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle strictly distinguishes between runtime and compiletime dependencies.

Transitive dependencies like the ones defined by `com.avios:component-starter` the are only applied for compiletime if the library defines them in the `api` scope. All dependencies declared as `implementation` are not visible for compilation of other modules.

Unfortunately eclipse has only a single scope that holds both runtime and compiletime dependencies - which is why this type of issues are not visible within the IDE.

If your `component-starter` is of type `java-library` you should simply be able to change all dependencies that should be visible to clients as `api` instead of `implementation`.

If this is not an option (e.g. you can only adjust the gradle file shown) you can also include the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` for scope `implementation` again to get rid of the errors

Comment: Thanks for the help. The answer is accurate and to the point. Saved a lot of my time.